# Only one analog-connected speaker makes audible sound

Tags: raspbian, pi-3

I have speakers, similar to the ones [here.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01HCER02W) I am able to connect them to the raspberry pi 3 using the 3.5 mm input. There is one main speaker, that can works independently, and there is an additional speaker that can work together with the main one. Whenever I connect only the main one, the sound is barely audible. When I connect both, I notice that it is only the helper speaker making the sound. I tested the same thing out by connecting the main speaker with a cord to my iPad, and it worked fine.

Is this a speaker issue or a raspberry pi? Is there any way I can try to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, I realized that the cause of my problem was a slightly faulty 3.5mm output on the main speaker. I had to use more force to plug the cord in. What essentially happened was that the main speaker was getting weak signals due to the cord not being plugged in, but still gave the correct signals to the helper speaker.

Answer (score 0):

From the pictures it looks like the main speaker needs power via mini USB and audio via 3.5mm cable, and it then provides audio to the second speaker via the cable coming at its base.

If that is the case, I would venture the Pi can drive the speaker without power but would be barely audible, since the speaker's amplifier wouldn't be powered, so I would try the following and please report back:

1. Ensure main speaker has power. Power adapter to mini USB and Pi audio to 3.5mm input. It should then be loud with or without second speaker connected.

Hope that helps.

Comment: My speakers might be a little bit different than the one in the link since the main speaker does not need power - it gets charged beforehand. If the PI struggles to power one speaker, it wouldn't really make sense for it to be able to power the second one. In addition, this all works fine with a phone, which I doubt can power two speakers. I'll try your suggestions about powering it anyways.